# Android Dagger/Hilt [DuplicateBindings] - Add Test Modules Only For One Specific Testing Class

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger-hilt

I'm using the @UninstallModules annotation in one of my test classes to change the actual dependencies with the mock ones. Therefore, I create duplicates of those modules in my testing package.

The problem however is that it causes confusion for the dagger compiler. I get the [Dagger/DuplicateBindings] error on every class if I don't uninstall the testing modules with  @UninstallModules for all of them.

How can I make the dagger modules specific to one class?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace a production object with a test double (mock, fake etc.) for **all tests**:

1. Add a test Dagger module as **a separate file** in your `test` source-set (directory).
2. Use `@TestInstallIn` annotation on top of that test Dagger module, in order to replace the production Dagger module.

Example:

```kotlin
@Module
@TestInstallIn(
    components = [SingletonComponent::class],
    replaces = [AnalyticsModule::class]
)
abstract class FakeAnalyticsModule {

  @Singleton
  @Binds
  abstract fun bindAnalyticsService(
    fakeAnalyticsService: FakeAnalyticsService
  ): AnalyticsService
}
```

---

If you want to replace a production object with a test double (mock, fake etc.) for **a single test class**:

1. Use `@UninstallModules` annotation on top of your test class.
2. Create a test module with `@InstallIn` annotation **inside** the test class.

Example:

```kotlin
@UninstallModules(AnalyticsModule::class)
@HiltAndroidTest
class SettingsActivityTest {

  @Module
  @InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
  abstract class TestModule {

    @Singleton
    @Binds
    abstract fun bindAnalyticsService(
      fakeAnalyticsService: FakeAnalyticsService
    ): AnalyticsService
  }

  ...
}
```

---

See [this document](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-testing#testing-features) for an overview of Hilt testing features.